# CakePHP route does not receive parameter

Tags: cakephp, routes

I've created a router in `route.php` as shown below

```
Router::connect('/reset-password/:token/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'resetPassword'));
```

When i access the web site `example.com/reset-password/something` the function `resetPassword` returns `null`.

> Users controller

```
public function resetPassword($token = null) {
        
    $this->layout = null;

        
    echo $token;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `Router::connect('/reset-password/*'`... ?

Comment: That's worked! Why did using :token not worked?

Comment: because you must set token pattern  in connect options https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/routing.html#configuring-route-options